# Generating a unique Hash based on DateTime and String parameter

Tags: c#, datetime, hash

I would like to create a function which would enable me to generate unique values always based on these two entry parameters:

```
public string ReturnUniqueValue(DateTime date, string ID)
{
 // Logic here
}
```

The date parameter is in the following format:

```
2017-08-14 11:55:32.00
```

While the ID is in the following format:

```
112452573848
```

I would like to generate a unique hash which is 40 characthers in length and that it never repeats.

Is this doable with datetime parameter + unique id string ?

I figured that datetime is never the same (it's nearly impossible), thus this should be able to always generate unique value?

Comment: It is possible that you get duplicates from combining these 2 (unless ID is always unique). If you want a somewhat unique string, look into `Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: @Shyju yes the ID is always unique, what would be the best way to hash this ? :)

Comment: @adiga that's just combining two strings? :D

Comment: Use Guid instead, it was created exactly for this. With your method I could pass the same DateTime instance and ID field as many times as I wanted

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I can't use GUID because the data comes from API source, and I need to somehow hash it in order to compare the values that  I have in my DB and from API ^^

Comment: Well, you could use something like `date.GetHashCode() + int.Parse(id)` or `date.Ticks + int.Parse(id)` or `((new { date, Id }) as object).GetHashCode()`. There are many different ways that will create very different hashes, which one is preferred is up to you. Do notice that `date.Ticks` is unique unless the exact same time was passed twice

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I should always get the same hash value for specific ID + Date , thus the date.ticks isn't needed no ?

Comment: _"I would like to generate a unique hash"_ -- you are asking for the impossible, especially if your hash is only 40 "characters" (do you mean bytes? or 40 hexadecimal characters? or 40 base64 characters? or something else?). Your question fundamentally doesn't make sense. You need to be more clear about what kind of value you're trying to generate. Does it _really_ need to be unique? Or is it sufficient to create a hash value, which you can then follow up with later with an actual equality comparison as needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can

- write all your parameters (whichever) into a stream
- compute a hash using your favorite algorithm (e.g. SHA265)
- and return its first 20 values (= 40 characters) as a final result

In code:

```
public string ReturnUniqueValue(DateTime date, string ID)
{
    var result = default(byte[]);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            writer.Write(date.Ticks);
            writer.Write(ID);
        }

        stream.Position = 0;

        using (var hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            result = hash.ComputeHash(stream);
        }
    }

    var text = new string[20];

    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        text[i] = result[i].ToString("x2");
    }

    return string.Concat(text);
}
```

Note: if you just want a single unique value for multiple parameters, a simple concatenation should already do it. Since you explicitly asked for a "hash" with 40 characters, this more elaborate solution may fit somehow better.

Attention: extending this to more parameters of the same type (e.g. two strings) should include the parameters position within the stream to avoid collisions ((a, b) != (b, a)).